# Laravel [QUERY] how to select contents from table 1 where condition must meet in table 2 and table 3

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am stuck in building a query where I need to select items from table 1 if the condition is met on table 2 and table 3.

I have these three tables:

```
company -> company_id, name, location

services -> company_id, service_id, service_name

date -> service_id, service_date //should i include company_id here?
```

I want to select **company -> name and location** if the search matches **services->service_name and date->service_date.**

How can I JOIN tables to obtain the desired result?

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should include a clear outline of your *specific* coding-related issue, a summary of what you have already tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Comment: You should not have a table solely for the purpose of storing a timestamp (ie. get rid of the `date` table). Make the `service_date` field a part of the `services` table and join `company` and `services` on `company_id` with a WHERE clause that specifies a date range and/or a `service_name`.

Comment: @chb But one service can have many dates, and there's a time associated as well, so I think normalization is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't tested, but it will be something like the following:

```
$query = Company::query()
  ->select(['company.name','company.location'])
  ->leftJoin('services', 'services.company_id', '=', 'company.company_id')
  ->leftJoin('date', 'date.service_id', '=', 'services.service_id')
  ->where('services.service_name', $servicename)
  ->where('date.service_date', $servicedate);
```

Comment: Thank you, had to make some additions, but thank you, you were the only answering me, and it helped me a lot :)